# Scroll droppable area while scrolling

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have list of draggable elements in one div and list of droppable elements in another div.I want to pick the elem from draggable elements and drop on droppable elements. I have scroll for droppable container. While dragging and dropping, If the draggable element reaches the end position on droppable container, I need the droppable container to be scrolled (i.e the default behaviour of browser scroll, when mouse point reaches to end point it automatically scrolls).

I am using jquery drag and drop component. The droppable container scroll is not page scroll. I have so many divs and so many scrolls in the page and one of them is droppable container list.

my code is:

```
elem.addClass(randomClass)
.draggable({ appendTo: "body, helper: 'clone' });
```

Currently, the droppable container is not scrolling while dragging on droppable area. I have seen all the solutions but did not get what I need. All the solutions are related to page scrolls. Please help me.